# How can I include classic VB asp .inc in C# aspx?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Can anybody explain me how I can include .inc file from VB classic ASP in C# aspx page?

I try do it with:

```
<!-- #include file="menu.inc" -->
```

But I receive error about syntax in menu.inc "Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected" - "Line 3:    if Len(Session("GUID")) < 1 Then":

```
  <%
if Len(Session("GUID")) < 1 Then
    Response.Redirect "default.asp"
End If
  %>
```

Comment: I think part of the problem is that the c# compiler does not understand VB code...can you just convert vb asp into c# aspx?

Comment: i agree with Jeremy. But try once and write the classics asp tags under <Script type="vbscript">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Old now, but to add to it anyway:

ASP.Net is pre-compiled. Server-side includes tend to be interpreted. They just don't mix well.

To replace includes, ASP.Net supports master pages, user controls, and class libraries.